# HIPAA release form for travel insurance

Tags: united-states, insurance, travel, hipaa

This is all USA related.
I'm filing a claim to cover my medical expenses that happened on a trip abroad. Some related expenses happened in the US after I got back. The insurance company sent me an "authorization to disclose health information and other records" form. It allows me to fine tune what to share but should I allow them to get any information? I have all the related bills and paperwork submitted already. The form is very scary, e.g:
"I understand any disclosure of information carries with it the potential for re-disclosure and the information may not be protected by federal privacy regulations."
What is this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they need to use your health information to process your claim, they very likely do not need to ask your permission in the first place, as explained in greater detail [on HHS's website](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-individuals/guidance-materials-for-consumers/index.html). So the more plausible explanation is that they already have everything they need to process your claim, and instead want to do *something else* with your health information. The most likely candidate for "something else," in my estimation, is some kind of marketing or bulk data collection.

If I were presented with a form such as the one you describe, I would first read it carefully, to determine whether the insurance company is explicitly claiming they need me to fill out the form in order to resolve my claim. If the form did say something like that, I would call the insurance company and ask them what exactly they plan to do with my information, why it is necessary to process my claim, and why they need a HIPAA waiver when HIPAA already allows them to use my health information to process a claim anyway.

On the other hand, if the form made no such claim, I would ignore it and wait for them to follow up (I suspect they wouldn't bother). If they did follow up, I would again call them and ask for specifics. If they denied my claim and cited the form, I would appeal it and complain to my state's [insurance commissioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insurance_commissioner).

Comment: Thank you so much! After reading it through again according to your guide, they in fact say that they can not require me to sign this in order to receive payments or benefits.